# Not working CSS in DIVI render (but working in Builder)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a website for a friend on Wordpress with DIVI and WooCommerce. My shop page worked until i loged in WooCommerce.

Now my page is the good one ine the builder but seems to be CSSless in real.

The following screen will explain quite much (*top* : in Divi Builder, what i want finally / *bottom* : what appears on the website).

[image: In DIVI Builder (the right page)]

[image: What i have in real]

Thanks.

Comment: when you go one a product page (like `...-drones.fr/produit/drone-1/`) you see buttons with the blue border. then you have to find in the CSS code, where is the conflict between the theme and woocommerce on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the solution. It works when i don't set my page as the woocommerce'shop page.